# What is this React syntax – <ReactMarkdown components={{pre() {}}} />?

Tags: reactjs

While exploring the `react-markdown` package, I noticed it has a strange way to customize components. It has props `components` and it accepts an object, but the syntax looks nothing like the regular `key: value` object syntax.

```
    <ReactMarkdown
      children={markdown}
      components={{
        pre({node, inline, className, children, ...props}) {
          return children;
        }
      }}
    />
```

Now, this does work, but I don't understand how. Is it possible to turn this into a regular `key: value` syntax?

Comment: The double curly braces could be intimidating but it's just a regular object being passed as prop, it has `pre` key that is a function, you could rewrite it like this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dn2f8d?file=src/App.js

Comment: @coglialoro Thanks! Please post this as an answer (along with the source code, inline) and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double curly braces could be intimidating but it's just a regular object being passed as prop, it has `pre` key that is a function, you could rewrite it like this:

```
const componentsObject = {
  pre: ({ node, inline, className, children, ...props }) => children,
};

return <ReactMarkdown children={markdown} components={componentsObject} />;
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-dn2f8d?file=src/App.js